# Why does Spider-Man shoot webs from his wrist in the movies?

Tags: spider-man, powers, super-hero, marvel, spider-man-2002

From what I remember, in the original comics, Spider-Man shot webs from his wrist because Peter Parker used his science background to design mechanical web shooters.

In the Sam Raimi movies, however, the webslinging is a side effect of the genetically-modified spider bite that gives him the rest of his powers.

My question is this: why would the spider DNA result in webs originating from his *wrists*?  Natural spiders create webs with spinnerets located at the tip of their abdomen.  Wouldn't it have been more believable if Spider-Man's webs came from, well, *behind* him?

Is there some explanation given as to why his web-producing organs appeared in his wrists, and not elsewhere?

Comment: While not an answer, there is in-universe precedent (sort of). Spiderman 2099, had physiological spinnerets.

Comment: Because [a more realistic place](http://www.krakowstudios.com/spinnerette/2010/03/31/03312010/) wouldn't have been “polite” enough for a mainstream movie.

Comment: "why would the spider DNA result in webs originating from his wrists?" In a comic book universe you just have to roll with things like this, "Real Life" explanations can always apply since in reality spider DNA would probably kill him. I'm no geneticist just speculating.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief

Comment: And in Spider-Man 2099, Miguel O'Hara expressed relief that he wasn't eating flies and shooting webs out of his butt. See also [Scientifically Accurate Spider-Man](http://devour.com/video/scientifically-accurate-spider-man/)

Comment: It's nothing to do with politeness and everything to do with pragmatism. Spider-man is an established comic book character. He has a known and very recognizable way of fighting and traveling. In order to do any of that, his webs have to shoot from his wrists.

If you wanna make him an actual spider, that would be a different character. He would need a different way of traveling and fighting (e.g. just sitting on a web all day and waiting for victims to get stuck so he can wrap them up and drink their juices).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté In point of fact, there are quite a few potential explanations for why the webs would shoot from his wrist beyond "to make him recognizable" (especially since there is apparently at least one comic story line that involves him [producing organic webs from his wrist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_powers_and_equipment#Organic_webs)). The question is about whether *an explanation is given*, and not "why isn't he an actual spider".

Comment: You asked _"wouldn't it have been more believable if spiderman's webs came from, well, behind him?"_ --that is essentially asking why isn't he an anatomically correct spider. To which I'm saying: then he can't behave like Spider-Man. He can't swing from his webs; he can fight like Spider-Man, and you essentially would be inventing a new character (as well as have to figure out a new fighting style that doesn't look ridiculous) for the movies. It's simply not practical to invent a whole new character just so he can produce his web from his butt.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Selectively choosing one light-hearted comment out of four paragraphs, and deliberately ignoring the rest, is called [cherry picking your arguments](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Cherry_picking). If I edited the single humorous comment out of the question, would that eliminate your entire complaint about the question?

Comment: Put another way, are most audiences going to Spider-Man movies in order to see arachnologic realism or to see Spidey doing his cool acrobatic moves swinging between skyscrapers and blasting silk (real or synthetic) from his wrists?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté So you're standing by the cherry picking, and insisting on ignoring the entire point of the question ("is there an explanation given"), just so you can lecture me about what people (presumably) want to see?  Got it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Beofett - Thank you for putting in my head [the image of Spider-Man shooting webs out of his butt](http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/More+realistic+tiny+spidey+spiderman+spiderman+shoots+a+web+from+his_a53654_5156783.jpg), swinging around from his butt, and spraying his enemies with butt-webs.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There's no in-universe answer.

Out-of-universe, they would have had to complicate an already long-running movie to add in an explanation of Peter's father's inventions, how Peter finally solved the adhesive problem, his testing of the fluid, etc.  It would have taken another 30-45 minutes to give any satisfactory explanation, which would have pushed the running time up to a fiscally inadvisable level.

The spinnerets become located in his wrists for no good reason.  The only reason they're there is because that's where Spiderman's webs come from.  Anything even approaching an accurate physical location would have taken the movie into an entirely different direction.

The studio would never have gotten *behind* that.  It would have been a waste of their *ass*ets to even consider it.

Comment: You can see an anatomically correct "Spider/Man" in a Venture Brothers episode.  [The Brown Widow](http://venturebrothers.wikia.com/wiki/Brown_Widow) was in an episode in Season 4.

Comment: Another (more or less) anatomically correct "Spider Man" (or rather Spider Girl) is the webcomic Spinerette. http://www.krakowstudios.com/spinnerette/

Comment: It would be kinda hilarious for the topic of a parody film though...

Comment: assets. Fnarr Fnarr

Comment: "It would have taken another 30-45 minutes to give any satisfactory explanation" - which was conveniently bypassed in the subsequent *Amazing Spider-Man* movie, where Peter pretty much just *bought his web spinners on the internet* (emphasis: my angry brain).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Strangely, I just rewatched that yesterday. I got the impression this time that he just straight up stole the technology. We see the cartridges when he's sneaking around Oscorp. It's a wonder nobody linked it immediately, you think they'd have CCTV in there.

Comment: @Phoshi: ah sure, yeah that would fit in better with the perennial “Spider-Man is broke” theme. There’s a little more discussion on the question here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33387

Answer (score 36):

Actually, scientifically and biologically it's fine for him to have spinnerets in his wrists. Research earlier this year has confirmed several species of tarantula (and therefore likely other spider species) really DO produce silk from their limbs as well as their abdomens; it's part of what helps them climb surfaces.

http://jeb.biologists.org/content/214/11/1874.abstract

Comment: Yep, and now researchers believe that spinnerets might have actually originated at the feet as a climbing aid, and then later evolved for silk making: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v443/n7110/full/443407a.html

Answer (score 11):

They wanted to keep the classic Spider-man look with his middle and ring fingers touching his palms while spinning webs, which is why they come from his wrists.

On the DVD behind the scenes they talk about the change from the web-slinging technology to the organic spinnerets. Stan Lee said that if he had thought of the spinnerets originally he would have used that, but since he didn't he had to come up with a technological explanation.

Answer (score 7):

**There IS a reason Spider-Man shot organic webbing from the top of his wrists. But to know how this came about, you need a bit of Spider-Man lore that is overlooked in the movie. This was the costume that changed where webbing came from in Spider-Man lore nearly thirty years ago.**

[image: The Famed Black Costume]

*The Famed (or infamous) Black Costume, first seen in the Secret Wars (1984)*

- Up to this point in Spider-Man comics, Peter Parker used his famously-home-designed web shooters which ejected a custom-made, super-strong, incredibly-adhesive, yet fast-dissolving polymer that Peter Parker called his webbing. (First seen in Amazing Fantasy #15)
- These webshooters were versatile and could create any number of uses for webbing from protective gear to handcuffs. Their greatest failing was they could run out of webbing and did so at the most inopportune times.

[image]

Then came 1984 and Marvel created a character called **[the Beyonder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonder)** and [**the Secret Wars**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Wars) were born. One of Marvel's largest crossover events at the time (possibly one of the earliest) and it brought a wide array of Marvel's most well-known and well-loved characters together in a cosmic struggle including one Peter Parker.

**The famed Black Costume was discovered during the Secret Wars run of stories and was an alien symbiote which bonded with Parker giving him a number of new abilities.**

- He could change his costume's appearance to any street clothes he desired. For the first time, Spider-Man could change without having to duck into an alley, or a phone booth or hanging upside down on someone's fire escape.
- His speed and agility were increased as the symbiote augmented his existing powers further.
- The most impressive change which found its way into movies 30 years later was the position of his web shooters. Previously held under his wrist, Parker had to turn his hand upward and depress the stud to launch his webbing.
- **His new organic web shooters were on the back of his wrist marked by a large white patch. The suit made its own webbing! And it appeared to have an inexhaustible supply. This location is the same location they used in the movie.**
- If this character design seem familiar to you, it should. The suit and Parker had a falling out when it tried to take over his mind and claim Parker's body as its own. With the help of the Fantastic Four, Parker quits dating the suit and they agree to see other people.
- The first person who wore the suit was a fellow named **[Eddie Brock and he took the name Venom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Brock)**. The suit eventually spawned (don't ask) and produced other symbiotes, one of them took the colorful sobriquet, **[Carnage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnage_%28comics%29)**.
- When the movies decided to take on the genetic transformation to Spider-Man, they decided to go with the positioning of the organic webshooters seen on the Black Costume, maybe as tribute, maybe to be different. But anyone who knew the Black Costume smiled remembering the first time we saw it in action.

So now you know, true believer.

Comment: Wonderful history lesson but don't see how this long monologue answers the question at all. Why the wrists and not the backside if no mechanical spinners AND no 'Black Costume' are involved?

Comment: Because writers are lazy and willing to reuse ideas no matter how long ago they might have been used. And seriously is anyone going to pay to watch a Spider-Man who is shooting web fluid out of his [rear-end spinnerets](http://devour.com/video/scientifically-accurate-spider-man/). My goal was to inform as to HOW such a decision could have been made. Not to ponder why he isn't an even more ridiculous character than he already was.

Comment: @Thaddeus I like this answer; I just don't think its a good fit for this question (and in fairness, this question is the first I asked on this site, and not one I would ask now). Given the (usual) quality of your answer, I tried asking a [new question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38174/1359) that might be a better venue for your answer, although my question may be deemed a bit too broad.  Feel free to edit the other question if you think it can be improved, too.  Thanks!