# Why does Venom's webbing come from above his wrists?

Tags: comics, marvel, spider-man, venom

I am watching the 1994 Animated Spider-man series,

It seems that in this version, Venom's webbing comes from the white areas on the top of his wrists, why is that?

Shouldn't the webbing come from the same place as Spider-man's?

Comment: Related: [Why does spiderman shoot webs from his wrist in the movies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3343)

Comment: @Gilles related, but not the same at all ^_^

Comment: Completely based off speculation: It was my understanding that venom's web came from the suit itself. Because of this technically the web could come from anywhere. As for why the tops of his wrists that might have more to do with who's in the suit, and during the 90's animated series it was Flash Thompson. Flash was a football player and a bully, so he did a lot of things with his fists. Shooting web from the top of his fists might feel more natural to him then the way Peter does it.

Comment: @onewho Venom in the 1994 series was Eddie Brock, **not** Flash.

Comment: @The Doctor: You're right, I'm wrong... For some reason I thought it was Flash at that point. Even so, Spider's webs are based off his web shooters while Venom's is based off the suit. The person in the suit should be able to control where the web shoots from. So it might still be a matter of preference.

Comment: Best. Spider-man. TV Series. Ever.

Comment: @MikeB that be true :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**There is no biological reason for it to come from that particular location. It could just as easily come from Venom's shoulders if that's what it wanted. There is no physical reason the webbing comes from that location other than the writers/artist wanted it to.**

[image: Spiderman, Black Costume, The Secret Wars]

*The black Spider-Man costume's first appearance in the Secret Wars. Note the location of the webshooters on the BACK of his hands.*

Venom's uniform is an artifical lifeform that was picked up by Peter Parker when he was involved the Marvel storyline The Secret Wars. The suit has always made its webbing from that location. But since the creature is a biological organism with complete control of its physical form, it could make webbing come from ANYWHERE.

The designers of the suit wanted an original appearance and to remind the readers this was not their Spider-Man, this was a new and improved model. The Black Spider-Man suit was one of the most popular upgrades to the character in a long time. Shooting webbing from a different location was a visual cue to remind the reader of a difference in the character.

The symbiote has been on of the most marketable characters for the Spider-Man line EVER. Venom, Carnage and its descendants have a visual appeal equaled by no other Spider-Man villain.

Comment: Yes, well I am basically asking why those white patches on the top of him arms and not just the same place as Spider-man?

Comment: I think they just did it to support him being "different". Almost as in being "reversed".

Answer (score 1):

The only people who really know the answer to this are the original writers and/or artists who designed the symbiote suit and Venom. My guess, though, is that Venom shoots webbing from the back of his hands ... because it looks cool. It kind of reminds me of a back-of-the-wrist-mounted poison dart or grapple hook that some miscellanious characters use in fiction.

Comment: This is no doubt the correct answer. It looks cool and it's different. There's also no reason for it to come from the same place Peter's came from because at the time, Peter's webbing came from web shooters.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing worth noting is the fact that Venom's webbing is part of him. It's created out of his own mass. So I'm pretty sure that it can move and stuff (for example, tighten around an enemy's neck). However, when Spidey wore the symbiote, the webbing was like his normal kind. And I'm pretty sure that the symbiote changed the webbing for him purposefully, so it wouldn't creep him out. As for Eddie, it had no reason to keep that from him. Flash Thompson's Venom(Agent Venom) has normal webbing, because that's the way he wants it to be. The Symbiote uses things from its hosts minds, such as Spider Man thinking of Spider Woman's suit, and the Symbiote giving him a similar costume. As for why the webbing came from above his wrists, I guess it was just something in Peter's mind that triggered it, and it has stayed that way through out the different Venoms.