# Does Spider-Man use secreted web or web cartridges?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, the-amazing-spider-man

When Spider-Man spurts web from his wrist to swing through the streets, does he use a cartridge fitted in his wrist, or is that a secretion of his body due to the radioactive spider bite?

In the Spider-Man movie, his wrist looks like it’s secreting the web, but in the Spider-Man game we have to collect cartridges to refill the web. Also in the game, even if the cartridge is not filled, some minimum amount of web is still there. Also in the latest movie, The Amazing Spider-Man, I think he uses a web cartridge fitted in the wrist.

Comment: Are you saying that the Spider-Man 1/2/3 games (the ones set in that particular Spider-Man universe) contain web shooters? Or are you comparing the Amazing Spider-Man game to Spider-Man 1/2/3?

Comment: I am saying the old Spider-man 1/2/3 games. The one with Mysterio and Symbiotes in them. We had to collect Cartridges.

Comment: Are game question on topic here?

Comment: it seems to largely depend on the writer, I have seen both in various spiderman cartoons

Comment: please note that Spiderman, at this point, is *not* part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, as the character is still owned by Sony...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does spiderman shoot webs from his wrist in the movies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/why-does-spiderman-shoot-webs-from-his-wrist-in-the-movies)

Comment: You can refer my answer here : http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109549/19834

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the comics he developed his own webbing, cartridges and [palm-mounted touch-sensitive triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spider-Man_webshooters.jpg).

In the [Sam Raimi movie trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film#Sam_Raimi_films) they changed this to organic webbing produced by his body.

In the [Amazing Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_(2012_film)) films they went back to cartridges, but they were developed by a bio-tech company rather than by himself.

Comment: Good answer.  It's probably worth noting that after the first movie came out they changed to organic webbing in the comics for quite a while to match, but this got retconned back and he's now back to web cartridges.

Comment: @Tynam: huh, I didn't know that. [Spider-Man 2099](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099) always had organic secreted webbing.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, Spider-man doesn't have organic webs when the comics started.  He got organic webs later in the comic series.

> In the "Disassembled" storyline Parker undergoes a transformation that
>   results in the ability to produce organic web fluid from his wrists,
>   and is able to fire his webbing in much the same manner as his
>   artificial web-shooters. According to the new 2007 Spider-Man
>   handbook, Parker has grown spinnerets in his forearms that terminate
>   in small pores at the junction of his wrists. By pressing down with
>   his middle fingers to his palm, he causes the pores to open and the
>   spinnerets to eject the organic fluid with a force equal to or greater
>   than that of his web-shooters.
>
> Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_powers_and_equipment) for more details.

In Sam Raimi's trilogy of Spider-man, he did not follow the real Spider-man comics' story and skipped the [Artificial Web-shooters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_powers_and_equipment#Artificial_web-shooters).

> **By the way Sam Raimi's script is inspired by [James Cameron scriptment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_%28film%29), which took the idea of organic web-shooters for
>   Stevens's Failed Script.  From 1985 there have been many scripts
>   written for the Spider-man . But James Cameron's Script got the most
>   attention and became the base of the 2002 film.**[source]

But the 2012 [The Amazing Spider-Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_%282012_film%29) follows a similar path of the comics and they chose the artificial web-shooter for their movie.

*Borrowed from my own answer from [M&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8168/why-does-the-amazing-spider-man-not-have-the-natural-power-to-shoot-web/8169#8169)*

Comment: One big advantage of biological-generated web shooting ability is almost unlimited supply enabling him to shoot as many webs he needs without getting "out of ammo" (as happened several times with the artificial web-shooters).

Answer (score 0):

In Stan Lee's and Steve Ditko's original design, Spider-Man has web-cartridges that fit into two webshooters mounted on each wrist. He carries up to 30 spare cartridges in a utility belt he wears around his waist (under the costume). Sam Raimi, for the first three Spider-Man movies, decided to make Peter Parker's webbing organic, because he didn't think the audience would believe that a highschool kid could manufacture artificial spider silk when real-life scientists (with all their resources and tools) couldn't, by the early 21st century, and still can't, eleven years later - at least, not in that way.