# Are the organs with which Spider-Man secretes organic webbing ever shown?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

So I understand that the webs Spidey uses are in fact generated from within his body and seem to project from his wrists (?) -- real spiders have spinnerets I think located on their abdomens.

Do the movies or comics ever get into details -- would a visual inspection of his wrists reveal an abnormality?

Comment: Traditionally Spidey's webs come from gadgets and not an inherent ability.

Comment: Except the Raimi's Spider-Man and Man-Spider appearances, the webs are from his web-shooters and not naturally secreted

Comment: the webs Spidey uses are in fact generated from within his body and seem to project from his wrists. *citation needed* :p

Comment: @Shreedhar well, "no" is an answer.

Comment: @SQB _Some_ universes, for example, the Raimi trilogy, have them as natural from him so that wouldn't be entirely correct.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot true, but what I mean is that an answer detailing that in original form and most forms, Spider-Man uses web shooters, and that only in Raimi's interpretation of Spider-Man does the web come from his own body, would be a good answer to this question.

Comment: The answer here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6326/92306

tells why the webs come out of his webs. An out-of-universe explanation, it is though.

Answer (score 6):

Spider-Man usually only has web shooters and the organic ones have occurred rarely in the comics and in the Raimi trilogy. To coincide with Raimi's trilogy and the change to have Peter have organic webs and not web shooters the comics also made that same change. To cut a long story short Peter is turned into a spider by Queen, births from the spider and ever since then his abilities were "replaced" and he uses organic webbing. He is once again back to web shooters since the "One More Day" arc though.

The *Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Spider-Man: Back in Black* gives us some detail on this and how it works along with a nice diagram of how his webs are produced.

> Since the Queen's transformation, Parker can produce silk from glands within his forearms, limited by his body's health and nutrition. These organic webs have many similar properties to the artificial webbing **though they require a week to decay rather than decomposing within two hours.**
>
> [image: Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Spider-Man: Back in Black page with updates on his abilities]
> <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>